# Spark-Hadoop-> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am encountering error while trying to read a file from hdfs into Spark. The file README.md is present in hdfs

```
 spark@osboxes hadoop]$ hdfs dfs -ls README.md
16/02/26 00:29:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-rw-r--r--   1 spark supergroup       4811 2016-02-25 23:38 README.md
```

In Spark shell, I gave

```
scala> val readme = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/README.md")
readme: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> readme.count
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_4
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_4 is StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1)
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG BlockManager: Getting block broadcast_4 from memory
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG HadoopRDD: Creating new JobConf and caching it for later re-use
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG Client: The ping interval is 60000 ms.
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG Client: Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (648679508) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from spark: starting, having connections 1
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (648679508) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from spark sending #4
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (648679508) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from spark got value #4
16/02/26 00:25:26 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getFileInfo took 6ms
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/README.md
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1143)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
        at <init>(<console>:49)
        at .<init>(<console>:53)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


scala> 16/02/26 00:25:36 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (648679508) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from spark: closed
16/02/26 00:25:36 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (648679508) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from spark: stopped, remaining connections 0
```

In core-site.xml, I have below entry:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

and hdfs-site.xml has below detail:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

Am I missing something here ?
My OS is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core), Hadoop is 2.7.2, and Spark is 1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6

Comment: After adding user/spark in the URI, I could successfully accessed README.md into Spark from HDFS.
`scala> val readme = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/spark/README.md")
readme: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:27 `

`scala> readme.count
res1: Long = 141 `

Answer (score 6):

This happens due to internal mapping between directories.
First go to the directory where your file (README.md) is kept. 
run command : `df -k .`.
You will get the actual mount point of the directory.
For example: `/xyz`
Now, try finding your file(README.md) within this mount point.
For example: `/xyz/home/omi/myDir/README.md`
Use this path in your code.
`val readme = sc.textfile("/xyz/home/omi/myDir/README.md");`

Answer (score 4):

By default, `hdfs dfs -ls` will ls your user home folder on hdfs, not the root of hdfs. You can easily verify this by comparing the output of `hdfs dfs -ls` and `hdfs dfs -ls /` . When you use the full hdfs URL, you're using an absolute path, and it's not finding your file (because it's located in your user home folder). When you use a relative path, the problem is gone :)

You may want to know that `hdfs dfs -put` will also use your hdfs home folder as the default destination for the file, not the root of hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case README.md file was in folder of Spark (spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7) in my home directory.

In this way the full path was "/home/sdayneko/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md"

I put this path into input variable:

```
val input = sc.textFile("/home/sdayneko/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md")
```

After that, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and found that if table is corrupted they you can get this issue.

`show partitions myschema.mytable;`
Result:
partitionkey=abc
partitionkey=xyz

and if you do ls on hdfs for table folder

`ls -ltr hdfs://servername/data/fid/work/hive/myschema/mytable partitionkey=abc`

you will get just partition folder which is mismatch.

while reading through spark ... you will get this issue

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.invalidinputexception input path does not`

you will have to do drop partition or msck repair table to resolve this issue.
Thanks & Regards,
Kamleshkumar Gujarathi

Answer (score -1):

Can you try changing your command to as below and then run

```
val readme = sc.textFile("./README.md")
```

Comment: `scala> val readme = sc.textFile("./README.md")`

`readme: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:27`

`scala> readme.count`

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/spark/README.md
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
....`